# Creating a file with dynamic name in cobol

Tags: file, cobol, mainframe, creation, jcl

We want to create a file with a date embedded in it which is derived from another file.
Consider a file A contains processing date '04/18/2015'. Now we want to create  a file with name 'XXXX.YYYY.04182015'.

Can it be accomplished using COBOL and JCL?

Comment: Yes, it can be accomplished

Comment: @LajosArpad no, it can't, in the sense that the DSN required is invalid. So it can be done, but it won't succeed.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why can't it be done with your Scheduler? What is the source of the date file?

Comment: Also, putting the date in that order helps with what?

Answer (score 2):

As @BillWoodger notes, this is normally done with a job scheduler such as Control-M, CA-7, etc.

Often people new to IBM mainframes don't know about generation data groups (GDGs).  Ask your colleagues about this feature built in to the OS.  It is possible your problem can be solved without building a DSN with a date as one of its qualifiers.

If you *must* have a dataset with a date as one of its DSN qualifiers, and you *must* create this in a COBOL program, then you can do it via dynamic allocation.

Modern mainframe COBOL compilers can call C runtime routines, which ship with Language Environment (LE).  You can call `fopen()` from your COBOL program, specifying the file name you wish to use.  This is one way to do dynamic allocation.

The downside to this technique is that your file name appears nowhere in the JCL.  Impact analysis tools may not find your program creating this file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to dynamically generate the JCL or JCLPROC. Use a COBOL program/sort to create the JCL/JCLPROC with the date required. Then run that JCL.
However, the example you gave cannot be created as the last piece 04182015 is all numbers. DSN name needs at least the first character to be a character. We normally keep a prefix DT. In your case it would be 'XXXX.YYYY.DT041815'.

My personal experience is, such names are created when file needs to be FTPed. If so, you can change the output filename in the FTP parm file using SORT.

Comment: If you check the JCL Reference, you'll see that it doesn't need to be a character, but there are limits and certainly a number can't be the first character of a qualifier. Why not DT150418?

Comment: @Bill Woodger Thanks for correcting, that's what I meant, the first character of qualifier.

Comment: If you can update your answer then, including, please, reorder the date elements to something more rational for computers, we can remove the comments. You don't have to be specific (unless you want to) you can say "it can't start with a number" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear what the answer is, but i want to add something:

The only exception to this are some non-mainframe versions of Cobol. In most of them you can assign a data name in the FD and change the value everytime you close and open it, thus changing the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Laterally thinking, but still a valid response :   It is possible to submit dynamically assembled JCL from a CICS program written in COBOL.

Thusly you would have used COBOL and JCL.

You would still be assembling a `DD DSN=......`  line (card ?). The rest would be boilerplate. The asynchronous nature of the submission would mean having to test for the file's existence if subsequently required.

Scheduling pre-processing would still be the accepted way,
INCLUDE the `DD DSN=...`  from a temporary file or VAR after building it. This is relatively easy with Control-M.

A round about way would be to write JCL as an output file from batch cobol that is submitted shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasonably easy ways to do this that will work depending upon your environment.  You can not easily do it with JCL without add on products or custom system symbols.

You can invoke REXX or TSO using their called batch interface and pass them the desired dataset name you want allocated to your dynamically created DDNAME.

You can call a small assembler program that does the same with the DYNALLOC macro.

You can use environment variables to describe the file to be allocated in pure Cobol as described here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21046577 and in the Enterprise Cobol Programming Guide.